# Liferay integration options

Tags: java, content-management-system, liferay

We have an existing large Java Web Application that is clustered across many servers.  We currently store our Word documents within our Oracle/BLOB and would like to move to a CMS solution like Liferay.    Ideally we would like to present our users a view of their directory/file within one of the pages of our existing application and implement some workflow on top of Liferay within our application.

I've been reading the Liferay documentation to get a good feel to how best integrate into an existing Liferay/CMS server and from what I can tell the only way is via Portlets and or IFrames.  So the integration happens in the GUI of the application.

We were hoping to integrate with Liferay within our Server calling SOAP/REST/JSON calls and then taking the results and displaying it within our application.

Could someone educate me on if this is feasible and if it is where I could get further information regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can integrate just at "view side", but a good choice consists in usign [Liferay ServiceBuilder](http://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/what-is-service-builder-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en).

It is a well documented Liferay's framework available for any custom portlet you want to write, allowing you to:
- automatically create a ready-to-use persistence layer (db DDL, ORM, cache configuration, transaction ecc...)
- expose local (in the same VM), remote (in the same VM, or by SOAP/REST/JS API/Mobile API) functionalities

You can surely combine both functionalities together, but you are free to use just one of them.

If it was a my choice, I would create a LR service wrapping the call to your external datasource.
In this way it will be able to partecipate in a distributed transaction (simply configuring a distributed transaction manager), to configure access to resource by using LR permissions framework, to be compliant with any kind of LR taglib (as SearchContainer: it should be very useful for showing a list of item)... and everything without the necessity to configure anything.

Several ways for achieving what I said are available... with a simple Google search I immediately fiund [this guide](https://www.liferay.com/it/web/ssrikanthreddy1410/blog/-/blogs/connecting-to-different-database-using-liferay-service-builder).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay allows you to write your own custom document store. You will need to implement few interfaces and configure LR to use it. That should do it. You can look at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.BaseStore and com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.DBStore to understand how it can be done.

Thanks